# Sorting files based on non empty lines Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I want to sort recursively found non-empty .py files (from current directory) in reverse order, based on the non-empty lines. If multiple files have equal number of non-blank lines, than the order should be alphabetical. All i have is:

`find -P . -name '*.py' ! size 0 -print | xargs cat | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l`

But this is not working and I don't know how to sort. I would prefer a one-liner instead of a bash script.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find py files, count non-empty lines with grep, revert columns with awk, and sort in inverse numeric order:

```
find -name '*.py' -exec grep -v '^$' -c {} -H \; | \
    awk -F: '{print $2, $1}' | \
    sort -nr
```

Answer (score -1):

`wc -l *.py | sort -n` will get you most of the way there.

`wc -l *.py | grep -vF ' 0 ' | sort -n` will eliminate the empty files.

Neither will handle recurse lookups, but that's not specified in your question, and I don't know how you'd go about alphabetizing in that case.

I think this does what you are asking:

```
 wc -l *.py | grep -vF ' 0 ' | sort -nr -k1,2 -t' '
```